# Fastest way to operate on individual bytes in an int

Tags: c#, performance, unsafe

I found that my application spends 25% of its time doing this in a loop:

```
private static int Diff (int c0, int c1)
{
    unsafe {
        byte* pc0 = (byte*) &c0;
        byte* pc1 = (byte*) &c1;
        int d0 = pc0[0] - pc1[0];
        int d1 = pc0[1] - pc1[1];
        int d2 = pc0[2] - pc1[2];
        int d3 = pc0[3] - pc1[3];
        d0 *= d0;
        d1 *= d1;
        d2 *= d2;
        d3 *= d3;
        return d0 + d1 + d2 + d3;
    }
}
```

How can I improve the performance of this method? My ideas so far:

1. Most obviously, this would benefit from SIMD, but let us suppose I don't want to go there because it is a bit of a hassle.
2. Same goes for lower level stuff (calling a C library, executing on GPGPU)
3. Multithreading - I'll use that.

**Edit:** For your convenience, some test code which reflects the real environment and use case. (In reality even more data are involved, and data are not compared in single large blocks but in many chunks of several kb each.)

```
public static class ByteCompare
{
    private static void Main ()
    {
        const int n = 1024 * 1024 * 20;
        const int repeat = 20;
        var rnd = new Random (0);

        Console.Write ("Generating test data... ");
        var t0 = Enumerable.Range (1, n)
            .Select (x => rnd.Next (int.MinValue, int.MaxValue))
            .ToArray ();
        var t1 = Enumerable.Range (1, n)
            .Select (x => rnd.Next (int.MinValue, int.MaxValue))
            .ToArray ();
        Console.WriteLine ("complete.");
        GC.Collect (2, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
        Console.WriteLine ("GCs: " + GC.CollectionCount (0));

        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew ();
            long res = 0;
            for (int reps = 0; reps < repeat; reps++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    int c0 = t0[i];
                    int c1 = t1[i];
                    res += ByteDiff_REGULAR (c0, c1);
                }
            }
            sw.Stop ();
            Console.WriteLine ("res=" + res + ", t=" + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString ("0.00") + "s - ByteDiff_REGULAR");
        }
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew ();
            long res = 0;
            for (int reps = 0; reps < repeat; reps++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    int c0 = t0[i];
                    int c1 = t1[i];
                    res += ByteDiff_UNSAFE (c0, c1);
                }
            }
            sw.Stop ();
            Console.WriteLine ("res=" + res + ", t=" + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString ("0.00") + "s - ByteDiff_UNSAFE_PTR");
        }

        Console.WriteLine ("GCs: " + GC.CollectionCount (0));
        Console.WriteLine ("Test complete.");
        Console.ReadKey (true);
    }

    public static int ByteDiff_REGULAR (int c0, int c1)
    {
        var c00 = (byte) (c0 >> (8 * 0));
        var c01 = (byte) (c0 >> (8 * 1));
        var c02 = (byte) (c0 >> (8 * 2));
        var c03 = (byte) (c0 >> (8 * 3));
        var c10 = (byte) (c1 >> (8 * 0));
        var c11 = (byte) (c1 >> (8 * 1));
        var c12 = (byte) (c1 >> (8 * 2));
        var c13 = (byte) (c1 >> (8 * 3));
        var d0 = (c00 - c10);
        var d1 = (c01 - c11);
        var d2 = (c02 - c12);
        var d3 = (c03 - c13);
        d0 *= d0;
        d1 *= d1;
        d2 *= d2;
        d3 *= d3;
        return d0 + d1 + d2 + d3;
    }

    private static int ByteDiff_UNSAFE (int c0, int c1)
    {
        unsafe {
            byte* pc0 = (byte*) &c0;
            byte* pc1 = (byte*) &c1;
            int d0 = pc0[0] - pc1[0];
            int d1 = pc0[1] - pc1[1];
            int d2 = pc0[2] - pc1[2];
            int d3 = pc0[3] - pc1[3];
            d0 *= d0;
            d1 *= d1;
            d2 *= d2;
            d3 *= d3;
            return d0 + d1 + d2 + d3;
        }
    }
}
```

which yields for me (running as x64 Release on an i5):

```
Generating test data... complete.
GCs: 8
res=18324555528140, t=1.46s - ByteDiff_REGULAR
res=18324555528140, t=1.15s - ByteDiff_UNSAFE
res=18324555528140, t=1.73s - Diff_Alex1
res=18324555528140, t=1.63s - Diff_Alex2
res=18324555528140, t=3.59s - Diff_Alex3
res=18325828513740, t=3.90s - Diff_Alex4
GCs: 8
Test complete.
```

Comment: Why are you going through memory? Have you tried just shifting to get the individual pieces?

Comment: We need the full context,  but you can use c++/cli and use openmp with c++.  Or use c# parallel.For but we need to see how you use your code

Comment: I think, most slowness comes from 4 squares, like x*x; Input is char; you can try to use pre-computed table for squares[256]; don't forget turn index to unsigned char.

Comment: @maxihatop According to the profiler the hotspot is the final addition, but I will try your suggestion and update the results.

Comment: @mafu, you should try to run the benchmark again, using the `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` attribute for the methods (and the fix for the stupid bug in my "option 3").

Comment: @maxihatop Pardon, but could you explain again how you would convert the index? I don't see a clear way to get rid of the sign.

Comment: Have you tried `ByteDiff_REGULAR` with `int` values instead of `byte`. Not sure if it makes any difference, but may..

Comment: Since you're trying to time such fast calculations with many iterations it is also worth tracking the number of garbage collections that get performed and only compare timing information between runs with the same number of GCs. I generally create a histogram of the number of GCs to get the average and can then use this to extrapolate the actual time taken to run the code I'm trying to profile.

Comment: @Enigmativity That is a very good remark, though in my case, there is almost nothing to be collected, and the overall object count is very low. I've added code to verify no collection occurred during the test.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I tried and it did make a difference, about 10% faster. I changed the type of all `c**` variables to `int`, I did not change the `(byte)` cast in the same lines because it is required for correctness.

Comment: @mafu - My tests also showed there was very little to be collected. It is a good thing to keep in mind though.

Answer (score 4):

> Most obviously, this would benefit from SIMD, but let us suppose I don't want to go there because it is a bit of a hassle.

Well avoid it if you want, but it's actually fairly well supported directly from C#.  Short of offloading to the GPU, I would expect this to be by far the largest performance winner if the larger algorithm lends itself to SIMD processing.

http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/simd-enabled-vector-types-with-c/240168888

> Multithreading

Sure, use one thread per CPU core.  You can also use constructs like Parallel.For and let .NET sort out how many threads to use.  It's pretty good at that, but since you know this is certainly CPU bound you might (or might not) get a more optimal result by managing threads yourself.

As for speeding up the actual code block, it may be faster to use bit masking and bit shifting to get the individual values to work on, rather than using pointers.  That has the additional benefit that you don't need an unsafe code block, e.g.

```
byte b0_leftmost = (c0 & 0xff000000) >> 24;
```

Comment: SIMD: Granted, the articles make it look even easier than I thought. I will give it a try. -- I had a quick look at MT and the speedup appears to be close to linear (as expected), though I did not verify this yet. -- Any other ideas what could be done?

Comment: Have you benchmarked dropping the unsafe / pointer stuff for bit masking & shifting?  I suspect that will be faster.

Comment: Yes, I edited it into the question, unsafe is slightly faster. I am not sure if the code is how you imagined it, it is pretty much the naive C#-only solution.

Comment: Have a look at the implementation options that @Alex offered. `and data are not compared in single large blocks but in many chunks of several kb each` Make sure that you process data that is close together in memory (as best as you can control it) together, to increase the chances of a CPU cache hit.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the already mentioned SIMD options and running multiple operations in parallel, have you tried to benchmark some possible implementation variations on the theme? Like some of the below options.

I almost forgot to mention a very important optimization:

- Add a `using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;`
- Add the `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` attribute to your method.

Like this:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static int Diff(int c0, int c1)
{
    unsafe
    {
        byte* pc0 = (byte*)&c0;
        byte* pc1 = (byte*)&c1;
        int sum = 0;
        int dif = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++, pc0++, pc1++)
        {
            dif = *pc0 - *pc1;
            sum += (dif * dif);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static int Diff(int c0, int c1)
{
    unchecked
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int dif = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            dif = (c0 & 0xFF) - (c1 & 0xFF);
            c0 >>= 8;
            c1 >>= 8;
            sum += (dif * dif);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static int Diff(int c0, int c1)
{
    unsafe
    {
        int* difs = stackalloc int[4];
        byte* pc0 = (byte*)&c0;
        byte* pc1 = (byte*)&c1;
        difs[0] = pc0[0] - pc1[0];
        difs[1] = pc0[1] - pc1[1];
        difs[2] = pc0[2] - pc1[2];
        difs[3] = pc0[3] - pc1[3];
        return difs[0] * difs[0] + difs[1] * difs[1] + difs[2] * difs[2] + difs[3] * difs[3];
    }
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static int Diff(int c0, int c1)
{
    unsafe
    {
        int* difs = stackalloc int[4];
        difs[0] = (c0 >> 24) - (c1 >> 24);
        difs[1] = ((c0 >> 16) & 0xFF) - ((c1 >> 16) & 0xFF);
        difs[2] = ((c0 >> 8) & 0xFF) - ((c1 >> 8) & 0xFF);
        difs[3] = (c0 & 0xFF) - (c1  & 0xFF);
        return difs[0] * difs[0] + difs[1] * difs[1] + difs[2] * difs[2] + difs[3] * difs[3];
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited your suggestions in - sadly it seems they don't run faster. Their relative speed looks strange to me, I would have expected the bottom ones to be much faster. Oh, and the third one does not produce the same calculation result.

Comment: And kudos for your ideas, I was trying to think of different ways to implement this but could never have come up with yours.

Comment: Look at the edit. An important optimization is to add the `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` to your methods. Also fixed option 3 (a rather stupid bug).

Comment: Thanks, 3 works now. ... and I just noticed 4 is not working ^^; -- I think I need .net 4.5 for `AggressiveInlining`, I forgot to mention I am on 4.0. I will install 4.5 tomorrow and try it.

Comment: @mafu, it has been available since .NET 1.1 as fas as I am aware, see [MethodImplOptions Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you will need to add a `using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;`

Comment: I just checked, the `AgressiveInlining` was added in 4.5, 4.0 only offers the  rest. I guess it was part of the Roslyn update. I'll try it tomorrow, maybe 4.5 has different performance in other areas, too.

Comment: @mafu, I just checked using your benchmark code, it shaves off far less than I had expected, around 0.2 seconds for the `ByteDiff_UNSAFE` on my system in an x64 release build (from 1.49 to 1.29).

Comment: Guys, you need agressive loop unrolling(remove loops at all, ideally), not only agressive inlining. `for` loop includes checking if i < 4 after each loop body execution. That will kill any performance gains (see branch prediction) in first too cases.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reduce IL instructions count (looks like it's only option for single threaded, no-SIMD code). This code runs 35% faster than in description on my machine. Also i was thinking that you could try to generate IL instruction by yourself via Emit static class. It can give you more accuracy.

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static int ByteDiff_UNSAFE_2 (int c0, int c1)
{
    unsafe {
        byte* pc0 = (byte*) &c0;
        byte* pc1 = (byte*) &c1;
        int d0 = pc0[0] - pc1[0];
        d0 *= d0;
        int d1 = pc0[1] - pc1[1];
        d0 += d1 * d1;
        int d2 = pc0[2] - pc1[2];
        d0 += d2 * d2;
        int d3 = pc0[3] - pc1[3];
        return d0 + d3 * d3;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, as well as a similar patch for the "regular" version, and got inconsistent results. Sometimes it was slightly faster by (about 1%), more often it was the same speed for the "regular" version about about 5% slower for the "unsafe" version. It appears to depend on how hot the VM is (first time executed).

Comment: So we just need to add warmup stage to remove jitting time from performance testing. Here i compared 3 versions with quiet different executiion time. Check on your machine, if you want http://pastebin.com/LvCidNvJ

Comment: Here is your regular method with almost 2x lesser IL instructions and faster than your UNSAFE version http://pastebin.com/Mr6gHgg1

Comment: (Actually, on my machine it was slower when the VM was hot.) I'll try your links when I'm back home.

Comment: Timing for these variants on my system (Win 7, x64, Core I7): 

`t=1.92s - ByteDiff_REGULAR`, 
`t=1.42s - ByteDiff_UNSAFE`, 
`t=1.34s - ByteDiff_UNSAFE_2`, 
`t=1.64s - ByteDiff_REGULAR_2` (your last pastebin).  

Without `AggressiveInlining` around 15-25% slower.

Comment: I think that is quiet good for such amount of calls, next step can be  generating more accurate IL(if possible) or go native with simd and assembler. Good luck.